# Update Forecast Quota on Inactive User

Tags: apex

Is it possible to update a Forecasting Quota to 0 for Inactive Users ?

I got : INACTIVE_OWNER_OR_USER

Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately no, you'll either need to change the Owner to an active user, or, temporarily reactivate the User and deactivate them again.

Comment: Thank's. When I active a user, a mail is sent to the mail adresse or not ?

Comment: @JeremyDeseez No, they'd only receive an e-mail about their account either on creation, on e-mail change or on password reset. There may be some other scenarios, but reactivating someone is not one of them.

Comment: Many thanks. Are you good in Apex ? I'm stuck on a simple thing

Comment: @JeremyDeseez I'd be happy to look. Best to mark this as answered and write that in a separate question though. :)